# Access remote git repo via ssh, using libgit2sharp

Tags: libgit2sharp-ssh

I'm trying to get a simple working example for cloning or accessing a remote git repository via ssh. 
After adding nuget package `LibGit2Sharp-SSH v1.0.22`, got a .Net Framework v4.6.1 console application like this:

```cs
using LibGit2Sharp;
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string localPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "Example");
        string repoPath = "git@example.server.com:Projects/Project1.git";
        Repository.Clone(repoPath, localPath, new CloneOptions() { CredentialsProvider = CredentialsHandler });
    }

    private static Credentials CredentialsHandler(string url, string username, SupportedCredentialTypes types)
    {
        var sshDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), ".ssh");
        return new SshUserKeyCredentials()
        {
            Username = username,
            Passphrase = string.Empty,
            PublicKey = Path.Combine(sshDir, "id_rsa.pub"),
            PrivateKey = Path.Combine(sshDir, "id_rsa")
        };
    }
}
```

This returns `'Failed to start SSH session: Unable to exchange encryption keys'`.

If I use instead

```cs
repoPath = "ssh://git@example.server.com:Projects/Project1.git";
```

Then it throws `Malformed URL 'ssh://git@example.server.com:Projects/Project1.git'`.

Comment: The colon in the URL should be followed by a port number. If you're not supplying a custom port, then don't use the colon.  Also, you need a forward slash between the host and the path.  So either 'git@example.com:portNumber/Projects'  or 'git@example.com/Projects'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use '/' instead of second ':', to fix 'Malformed URL'

```
repoPath = "ssh://git@example.server.com/Projects/Project1.git";
```

As for 'Failed to start SSH session', that's a problem with libgit not LibGit2Sharp, should be tuned on OS level.